# Remove all HTML tag residing td tag and leave text Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table inside a td tag and i want to remove some elements (`table` `tr` `td`) inside of it but at least i want to retain the data inside of it

Here is the Sample code

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td>some data</td>
       <td>
       <table><tr><td>But i need to retain this data</td></tr></table>
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$('table td:has(table)').text(function(){
    return $(this).text()
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/99EHB/)